# Get null if not found in the database Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with Eloquent, my query is:

```
$b = Dictionary::find($a,$LangtoTranslate);
```

The problem is `count($a)` is 67, `count($b)` is 64..can I get null if value is not founded? In my case, the missing row in $a are "" but I need to have `null` or `""` if not I lost syncronism.

The `$a` is a simple array:

```
array:67 [▼
  0 => ""
  1 => "Frase fatale non identificato"
  2 => "Indice fuori dei limiti"
  3 => "Errata configurazione del componente"
  4 => "Raggiunto il numero massimo di annidamenti"
  5 => "Id sequenza non identificata"
  6 => "Rassegnazione"
  7 => "Salto ad uno step coesistente"
  8 => "RETURN senza passare dal via"
  9 => "Da Implementare"
```

The DB is made just from language columns:

| it- IT | en-GB | de-DE | Other Languages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italiano | English | Deutsch |  |

i've tried olso:

```
$b = Dictionary::where($reflang,$a)->first($LangtoTranslate);
```

But I get `null`

For reference:

```
$reflang = 'it-IT';

$LangtoTranslate = [ array of languages ]; => ex: ['en-GB','de-DE']
```

Comment: Can you post `$a`'s value? Also, what are the columns for `Dictionary`'s table?

Comment: @IGP ok, five minutes

Comment: You can try to make an array of `$b`,  loop through $a and foreach index insert the find function in the database and array_push it to `$b`

Comment: @Nemoko nothing...don't return the emptry rows....

Comment: Yes because its empty, it doesnt return anything. make an if statement and check if its empty or not. if its empty array push null else array push $b

Comment: @Nemoko but the result array is smaller olso if string are not founded, and this is bring to me to search one row for times....4782 query...

Answer (score 0):

As it is unclear what you want to achieve since you only provide partial code I will have my own version of your code.

Instead of using `find()` you want to use the `where()` function.

```
$a = ["0","1","2"];
$b = [];

foreach($a as $text){
    $found =  Dictionary::where('YourColumn','=',$text)->first();
    if($found !== null){
        array_push($b,$found->YourColumn);
    }else{
        array_push($b, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I want is passing the array of string to the database to speed up the time, get the result and merge the translation with the starting array so I need that the result array should have the same size!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: using find() or where() is not a problem for me, actually is working like your example but, think about it: My excel file can be 2000 row or 14000 row, and using a foreach loop I will fire 2000 or 14000 query.

I would like to query a chunk instead row by row, but as I explained, if my chunk contain empty, string or I don't fine a row in the database, the returning value will be different ex: if I look in the db with find() or where() this-> `$a = [ '', '4r4n','Hello World']`  the result will be `dd($b); $b ['Ciao Mondo']`

Comment: With my code, if it finds null, it still is going to be pushed into the array when nothing is found.

Comment: Yes, and it's like actually my algorithm is working...but what I'm trying to do is not passing a value of the array like now but all the array  FROM THIS => `Dictionary::where('YourColumn','=',$text)->first();` TO THIS => `Dictionary::where('YourColumn','=',$a)->first();` in your case you have 3 values, but think to have an array with 87234 values....

Comment: I Need to find a way to use the mysql IFNULL function...